# update array index but its changing all index in IOS

Tags: ios, swift3

here i am trying to update particular value in index but its updating all the index

```
class salarty  {

var sal_id                        :String = ""
var sal_amount             :String = ""
var sal_iScreated          :Bool = false

init(sal_id : String, sal_amount : String, sal_iScreated: Bool){

   self.sal_id                =  sal_id
   self.sal_amount     =  sal_id
   self.sal_iScreated =  sal_id

}
}

class Employee {

    let id: Int, firstName: String, lastName: String
    var salaryArray  :[salarty]  = [salarty]()


    init(id: Int, firstName: String, lastName: String, salaryArray: [salarty]) {
        self.id = id
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName  = lastName
        self.salaryArray = salaryArray
    }
     }


array_SalaryDetails.append(salarty(sal_id : "2", sal_amount : "3000", sal_iScreated: false))

let employeeArray = [
    Employee(id: 1, firstName: "Jon", lastName: "Skeet",salaryArray :array_SalaryDetails),
    Employee(id: 2, firstName: "Darin", lastName: "Dimitrov",salaryArray :array_SalaryDetails),
    Employee(id: 4, firstName: "Hans", lastName: "Passant",salaryArray :array_SalaryDetails)
]
```

here i tried with some code its not working

Method 1 :

```
var model  = Employee[(indexPath?.section)!].salaryArray
        let model2 = model[(indexPath?.row)!]
        model = model.map{
            let mutableval = $0
            if $0.sal_id == model2.sal_id {
                mutableBook.sal_iScreated = !model2.sal_iScreated
            }
            return mutableval
        }
```

Method 2 :

```
    let model  = array_Main[(indexPath?.section)!].serviceArray
    let model2 = model[(indexPath?.row)!]

    model2.service_isSelected = !model2.service_isSelected
```

Comment: @s-murugan : Take a look at answer posted below and consider accepting it if it helped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats because in `Swift` instance of class are **passed by reference** and not **by value**.

So the salary array you created and passed to multiple Employee object they eventually had reference to same salary objects . So changing value of salary in any array in any Employee object would reflect change in all Employee objects

**Two possible solutions:**

**Solution 1: Preferred solution**

Change `salarty`  to be `struct` and not `class` and if possible change the spelling of salary as well :P

```
struct salarty  {
        
        var sal_id                        :String = ""
        var sal_amount             :String = ""
        var sal_iScreated          :Bool = false
        
        init(sal_id : String, sal_amount : String, sal_iScreated: Bool){
            
            self.sal_id                =  sal_id
            self.sal_amount     =  sal_id
            self.sal_iScreated =  sal_iScreated
            
        }
    }
```

**Solution 2:**

Create a deep copy of salary array for each Employee before assigning.

```
class salarty : NSObject, NSCopying  {
    func copy(with zone: NSZone? = nil) -> Any {
        let copy = salarty(sal_id: self.sal_id, sal_amount: self.sal_amount, sal_iScreated: self.sal_iScreated)
        return copy
    }
    
    
    var sal_id                        :String = ""
    var sal_amount             :String = ""
    var sal_iScreated          :Bool = false
    
    init(sal_id : String, sal_amount : String, sal_iScreated: Bool){
        
        self.sal_id                =  sal_id
        self.sal_amount     =  sal_id
        self.sal_iScreated =  sal_iScreated
        
    }
}
```

for each employee you can create a new array using either

```
    array_SalaryDetails.append(salarty(sal_id : "2", sal_amount : "3000", sal_iScreated: false))
    //salary array copy for first employee
    var firstEmployeearrayCopy = [salarty]()
    for salary in array_SalaryDetails {
        firstEmployeearrayCopy.append(salary.copy() as! salarty)
    }
    Employee(id: 1, firstName: "Jon", lastName: "Skeet",salaryArray : firstEmployeearrayCopy)

    //salary array copy for second employee
    var secondEmployeearrayCopy = [salarty]()
    for salary in array_SalaryDetails {
        secondEmployeearrayCopy.append(salary.copy() as! salarty)
    }
    Employee(id: 2, firstName: "Darin", lastName: "Dimitrov",salaryArray :secondEmployeearrayCopy)
```

or you can create array again n again for each employee.

In swift **Array** is **passed by value** but the objects (instance of class) in array will still be **passed by reference** as a result you will have to do all these workarounds :)

**Piece of Advice:**

Class names should start with capital letter. Only variable names follow camel casing.

Hope it helps

Comment: Hi  Sandeep 
array_SalaryDetails.copy() is not getting call

Comment: @s-murugan : ohhh sorry gimme a minute lemme update answer

Comment: @s-murugan : unfortunately you will have to create a separate copy for all the employees

Comment: @s-murugan : always welcome buddy :) One very interesting aspect of your question was when u create swift array its passed by value but if the array contains swift/objective-C objects in it they will be passed by reference in array :) Very interesting if u dig deep :) There are couple of questions on the same :) Take a look for deeper understanding